# CISSP Certification

Tags: cissp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good (preferably free) resource for CISSP practice questions](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1883/good-preferably-free-resource-for-cissp-practice-questions)

I am currently reviewing and aiming for a CISSP certification on the fourth quarter of this year. I've been reading the late Tipton's official isc2 guide for the CISSP CBK and watching some shon harris videos.

I know that this is a tough exam and I would like to hear your recommendations of a good community-base review similar with cccure.org and aside from those I have mentioned above.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think this question is appropriate for the QA format here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a Google search for CISSP questions, your going to get a ton of hits. A lot of these sites start going towards the more "unethical" means of the CISSP as you get into actual test dumps and what not. Then a lot of the other ones are honestly not going to help you a whole lot in preparation for the test IMO. From personal experience (taking the test 7 months ago), I would read Shon Harris's book from front to cover and then get another book that is more of a overview or highlight of everything. Basic IT/IS knowledge will normally narrow down your possible answers by 50%. From there, you need more detailed knowledge of what is going on to figure out what answer is the best. Shon Harris's book goes into those details, which is why I recommend reading it. Then before taking the test, you can get a general review book that may highlight a few things you didn't get from Shon Harris and also give you some good practice questions to test your knowledge.

Comment: I've got the shon harris' exam preps from a friend but those videos were like 5 years, I believe the concepts in general specially those which has been laid as a foundation in the industry is still applicable like for example access control methodologies. I was just thinking if that there might be some topics that were pulled off in the domains, something like that. I appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: This was my method of learning.
Real life experience --> Shon Harris book (detailed knowledge) --> Go through her practice tests --> Read a "cram" book for another author's perspective on questions and output. It's good to have the 2 different perspectives. Also, I would recommend listening to the Shon Harris audio material when your in your car or working out or something like that. Even if your not paying close attention, it's night to learn in various methods such as reading and also listening. You may pick up something you missed when reading. Good luck!

Comment: haha, that was exactly I did two weeks ago, converted the videos to audio and listening on it while on travel. Yes I believe the subliminal mind is powerful to catch up details. Thanks again!