# Suggested books to study for CISSP?

Tags: professional-education, certification, cissp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good (preferably free) resource for CISSP practice questions](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1883/good-preferably-free-resource-for-cissp-practice-questions)

I intend to study to take the CISSP exam within the next few months. Could anyone who's taken the CISSP please list the most helpful book you read to prepare for it?